# Proper Regex to find and replace escaped UTF-8 strings

Tags: javascript, regex, utf-8

(edited) I am reading a JSON file that includes some UTF-8 characters that are encoded like this: "`\uf36b`". I am trying to write a RegExp to convert this to an HTML entity that looks like "`&#x1F36B;`". This displays the character correctly in my html page.

I haven't been able to correctly display the character that should be associated with "\uf36b", especially when in a longer sentence that also includes other text.

How can I write a regexp that replaces strings like "\uf4d6" and "\uf36b" but leaves other text alone?

Example:

```
var str = "I need \uf36b #chocolate";
```

This should be converted to:

```
I need &#x1F36B; #chocolate;
```

Comment: Why `escape()` if you apparently don't want to escape it...?! Also, are we talking about Javascript here?

Comment: How did you come to have such a string?

Comment: Also, why does your input contain `\uf36b` (an invalid code point?) and your output contains `&#x1F36B` (note the `1`) — the actual code point for chocolate bar?

Comment: I got the string from a JSON file. I looked up the \UF36B character in an utf-8 table and concluded it had to be the chocolate bar...
I'm writing this in Javascript. Sorry for the unclear explanation :)

Comment: Also, I don't really want to escape it, that's just confusion on my part. All I really want is translate the string "\uf36b" so that my browser displays an emoticon - I do have a font that displays all unicode ranges. It works when I type "&#x1F36B;" manually. I just don't see how to convert the "\u..." string.

Comment: Your JSON data is bad, it looks like it should be trying to represent [U+1F36B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f36b/index.htm) but `\uf36b` is something else.  Trying to perform that conversion to fix your bad JSON data is not a good approach.  I found [this page](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode) to be pretty helpful, if you can change how the JSON data is generated it looks like you will want to use surrogate pairs.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\uf36b` here is a Unicode code point that represents a character, it should be possible to have your page support characters like this without needing to escape them by encoding to UTF-8.

That being said, the printable ASCII range is from `\u0020` (space character) to `\u007e` (tilde), so you should be able to use something like the following to only escape the characters you need to:

```
var escaped = "I need \uf36b #chocolate".replace(/[^\x20-\x7e]+|%/g, escape);
```

This will call `escape()` only on the non-ASCII or non-printable ASCII characters in your string, as well as any `%` characters.

You can then use `var str = escaped.replace(/%(..)/g,"&#x1f") + ";";` to do your conversion, although this looks pretty strange and I can't really see how it would do anything too useful.  You probably actually want something like the following:

```
var str = escaped.replace(/%(?:u([0-9a-f]{4})|([0-9a-f]{2}))/gi, "&#x$1$2;");
```

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear. All I really need is a way to convert a sentence that includes "\uf4d6" or "\uf36b" or similar codes, to a sentence that has HTML entities that I can actually display. I know that "&#x1F36B;" actually works, so it's really about the proper conversion.

Comment: Take a look at `"\uf4d6".length` in your console, you should get 1.  That sequence is just a representation for the character U+F4D6, to represent the literal characters `\uf4d6` the backslash would need to be escaped, like `"\\uf4d6"`.  This means that you can't just replace the `\u` in `"\uf4d6"`, there is no `\u` in that string.

Comment: I see! Man this is confusing.
Your code is almost working, except for 1 character. I get **"&#xuF36B;"** instead of **"&#x1F36B;"** - so there is a "u" where there should be a "1".

Comment: See my comment on the question, adding the "1" is a bad hack to fix the bad JSON data you are getting, there is probably a better solution.

Comment: Thanks :) I added a "1" to the final string before the $, like this: "&#x1$1$2;". Now it's working!

Comment: Yeah, if you are creating the JSON data in some other code of yours you should be able to get those higher unicode characters represented as a surrogate pair in the JSON, then you shouldn't need to do any encoding after reading it.

Comment: Thanks, I've checked and the strange encoding is indeed caused by faulty code on the server side. The JSON is created with Ruby/Java so I'm hoping they can fix it, so that it generates legal UTF8 characters.